# add .html only if none exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Google Webmaster Tools shows that there are some URLs indexed from the old site that do NOT have the .html suffix.
EXAMPLE: http://www.primocraft.com/Home-Bars/Kingston-Flat

The current site does have .html
http://www.primocraft.com/Home-Bars/Kingston-Flat.html

Will this work in my htaccess to resolve the 404 errors on the non .html urls?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: It should work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since the old urls doesn't seems to exists anymore, better do a 301 (Moved Permanently) to the new urls.